# InsertId in one table and insert the same id with concat of array at the end in other table

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables namely orders and suborders.

table 1 - Order table
Columns - Order Id and qty

Table 2 - suborders
Column - SubId

Whenever a new order is placed the same id has to be inserted in the both table but in the table 2 would I like to generate a the subid as  same id+ with iteration of total number of qty .

Eg

Table1

```
Exak123 , 59
```

I would like to get
Table 2

```
Exak123_1
Exak123_2 
..
.. 
Exak123_59
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single statement using a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

```
with new_t1 as (
  insert into table_1 (order_id, qty)
  values ('Exak123', 59)
  returning *
)
insert into table_2 (sub_id)
select concat(t1.order_id, '_', g.nr)
from new_t1 t1
  cross join generate_series(1, t1.qty) as g(nr);
```

Comment: lets say that a customer enters a order with certain quantity and i want to insert these information initialy into table1  then simoultaneously i want to generate the series in the table2  with combination of the respective newly generated id in table1 till quantity that matches the quantity.