# For every inserted row, generate series of rows in another table with AFTER INSERT trigger in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, trigger

Let's say that a customer places an order with certain quantity and I want to insert this information into `table1` initialy. At the same time, I want to generate a series of  rows in the `table2` with a combination of the newly generated ID in `table1`. Has to be executed for every new order. Like:

```
Table 1 
columns - id ,qty
          A1   25
          A2   32
```

Generates:

```
Table 2 
column - sub_id 
          A1_1
          A1_2
          .
          .
          A1_25
          A2_1
          A2_2
          .
          .
          A2_32
```

Comment: You already asked that question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/286548

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal easily with after insert trigger. First you need to create a trigger function which will collect information of newly added rows from table1 and will generate and insert a series of IDs into table2.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION after_insert_table1()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
         insert into table2 SELECT CONCAT(new.id,'_',generate_series(1, new.qty)) as sub_id;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Then you need to create the trigger on table1 which will call the trigger function.

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertIntoTable2 AFTER INSERT 
ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
execute procedure after_insert_table1()
```

This trigger will insert five rows into table2 with unique sub_id for satement **insert into table1 values ('A1',5);**

select * from table1

| id | qty |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 5 |

select * from table2

| sub_id |
| --- |
| A1_1 |
| A1_2 |
| A1_3 |
| A1_4 |
| A1_5 |

Comment: Thanks mate . I tried in the same way as yours but i made few errors your code helped me to understand better

Comment: You are most welcome. Thanks for accepting the answer. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely best handled in application code since it's a procedural goal you're trying to accomplish, not really a relational one, since the approach likely requires iteration.

That being said, you possibly can accomplish it in a relational way via [**Dynamic SQL**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-dynamic.html) if you had a `numbers` table you could select the `TOP` N number of rows from prepended with your `id`. The **Dynamic SQL** comes into play as a way to build the query with N = your `qty` field.

E.g. the query that your **Dynamic SQL** could generate would look like this (with `id` and `qty` filled in):

```
SELECT CONCAT('A1', '_', Number) AS sub_id
FROM NumbersTable
ORDER BY Number
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: `TOP 25` is valid in SQL Server, but not in Postgres (or standard SQL). And we don't really need the crutch of a "numbers table" in Postgres, either.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks, mind fart, fixed my example query.

Comment: I am also puzzled as to how dynamic SQL (or even ecpg!) would come into play. The `+` operator does concatenation in MS products, but not in Postgres (or standard SQL). We do not need an explicit cast, certainly not to `varchar(10)` with an arbitrary character limit.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks, the `+` was leftover from my brain fart, I've updated my answer with the PostgreSQL equivalent. The character limit is not arbitrary, the range of an `INT` in PostgreSQL is -2147483648 to +2147483647. I did forget about negative numbers though and have fixed my character limit to 11, even though assumptively in OP's case, he won't have negative quantities, but anything is possible I suppose. Clearly I'm not an expert on PostgreSQL :) so I don't know the exact **Dynamic SQL** implementation here, rather it's just an idea, but I believe it could be possible.

Comment: Also I re-updated my answer after re-reading that you said a cast isn't even needed. I decided to simplify it in that case with the `CONCAT()` function anyway. Thanks again for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

IN postgres you can use a `CTE` and `generate_series`  to build you desrired result

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1("id"  VARCHAR(3),"qty" int);
> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('A1',   25),('A2',  32)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table2 AS
> WITH sub_isbuild AS (
>   SELECT CONCAT("id",'_',generate_series(1, "qty")) as sub_id
>   FROM table1
> )
>  SELECT sub_id FROM sub_isbuild;
> ```
>
> ```
> 57 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table2
> ```
>
> ```
> | sub_id |
> | :----- |
> | A1_1   |
> | A1_2   |
> | A1_3   |
> | A1_4   |
> | A1_5   |
> | A1_6   |
> | A1_7   |
> | A1_8   |
> | A1_9   |
> | A1_10  |
> | A1_11  |
> | A1_12  |
> | A1_13  |
> | A1_14  |
> | A1_15  |
> | A1_16  |
> | A1_17  |
> | A1_18  |
> | A1_19  |
> | A1_20  |
> | A1_21  |
> | A1_22  |
> | A1_23  |
> | A1_24  |
> | A1_25  |
> | A2_1   |
> | A2_2   |
> | A2_3   |
> | A2_4   |
> | A2_5   |
> | A2_6   |
> | A2_7   |
> | A2_8   |
> | A2_9   |
> | A2_10  |
> | A2_11  |
> | A2_12  |
> | A2_13  |
> | A2_14  |
> | A2_15  |
> | A2_16  |
> | A2_17  |
> | A2_18  |
> | A2_19  |
> | A2_20  |
> | A2_21  |
> | A2_22  |
> | A2_23  |
> | A2_24  |
> | A2_25  |
> | A2_26  |
> | A2_27  |
> | A2_28  |
> | A2_29  |
> | A2_30  |
> | A2_31  |
> | A2_32  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b7f2fff1dfa8b5e2f5aefd3d5447e6a8)*

Comment: Is this possible to achieve via stored procedure and triggers ?

Comment: of course that is normal sql in  postgres, you must refine it, if you don't want duplicates. and if you don_'t want to create a new table, you  can use it in  nsert INTO. this is only  to show that it works and how in a simple manner

Answer (score 0):

Consider two separate columns in "Table 2", like:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (
  t1_id text PRIMARY KEY
, qty   int NOT NULL CHECK (qty BETWEEN 1 AND 1000)  -- CHECK to prevent abuse
);

CREATE TABLE tbl2 (
  t1_id  text  NOT NULL REFERENCES tbl1              -- optional FK
, sub_id int NOT NULL                                -- separate column !
, PRIMARY KEY(t1_id, sub_id)                         -- optional PK
);
);
```

Either way, a [**data-modifying CTE**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) in combination with [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) does the trick:

```
WITH ins1 AS (
   INSERT INTO tbl1(t1_id, qty)
   VALUES ('A1',  3)  -- input row once
   RETURNING *  -- !
   )
INSERT INTO tbl2(t1_id, sub_id)
SELECT i.t1_id, sub_id
FROM   ins1 i, generate_series(1, i.qty) sub_id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fbca5ea8e19e0976eded39a7187a1b12)*

You can still concatenate if you insist (for your original table layout):

```
WITH ins1 AS (
   INSERT ...
   )
INSERT INTO tbl2(sub_id)
SELECT i.t1_id || sub_id
FROM   ins1 i, generate_series(1, i.qty) sub_id;
```

But I wouldn't.

#### OR add a trigger

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tbl1_insaft()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tbl2(t1_id, sub_id)
   SELECT NEW.t1_id, sub_id
   FROM   generate_series(1, NEW.qty) sub_id;

   RETURN NULL;  -- AFTER trigger can return NULL
END
$func$;
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insaft
AFTER INSERT ON tbl1
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tbl1_insaft();
```

Then just:

```
INSERT INTO tbl1(t1_id, qty) VALUES ('A2',  4);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fbca5ea8e19e0976eded39a7187a1b12)*

Related:

- [Delete rows from a table depending upon rows deleted from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11060641/939860)